# Sencha Fiddle: Seems to be broken when trying to run or save files

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch-2

Does anyone know why Sencha Fiddle doesn't want to save files or run an application when it can be downloaded perfectly well?

The link to the fiddle is here:
http://new.senchafiddle.com/#/Fq0Lj/

I can run my code when I created it, but for some reason it won't run or save in the fiddle correctly.

Comment: This question doesn't belong to StackOverflow.

Comment: Sorry yes I didn't realise they had an issue tracker on GitHub. I will close/delete.

Answer (score 0):

I now use [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for my needs. But you can file an issue at the [project page](https://github.com/umrashrf/Sencha-Fiddle).

Comment: Thanks, see my comment below. Will delete/close.